# Display postback value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project and I found that the Session transferred value not being displayed in Label on first click. On clicking the button for the second time only the Session transferred value is being displayed. The sample code is below please let me know how to get the value displayed on the first click. Note: Value to be displayed inside the `IsPostBack` function as I am using lots of functions inside `IsPostBack`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string kitty = Convert.ToString(Session["ping"]);
        Label1.Text = kitty;
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string a = TextBox1.Text;
    Session["ping"] = a;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Session transferred value?

Comment: The value transferred over Session i.e. `a` in the current code.

Comment: Is your app load balanced across multiple servers? If so then you need to use SQL server to store your session state.

Comment: @hugh - Am sorry that's a huge code and am not interested to post it :-(  I am sure that this is a perfect code that describes my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just figured how what you mean. You need to do this. `PreRender` occurs after the button click and will pick up the new value.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string kitty = Convert.ToString(Session["ping"]);
        Label1.Text = kitty;
    }
}
```